# Cannot update / install anything

Tags: 16.04

I am trying to update some applications using the command

```
sudo apt update
```

But i am getting an error like below

```
E: Type 'https://packagecloud.io/AtomEditor/atom/any/' is not known on line 1 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/atom.list
E: The list of sources could not be read.
```

Ubuntu version: 16.0.4